# Is there a way to call an alertView from a tabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uialertview

I am trying to implement a way for a user to logout of my app through a custom tabBarController. I have 5 tabBarItems, and I want  the first one to be a logout tabBarItem - so when a user taps on it, an alertview pops up asking "are you sure you want to logout?". Is this possible - and if so what would be the best way about implementing this feature?

thanks!

-Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an unintuitive UI. I would consider redesigning so that there is a logout button somewhere within a view controller, toolbar or navigation bar.

With that said, if you *really, really* insist on making a "logout" tab bar item, you can create a `UIViewController` that presents a `UIAlertView` in `viewDidAppear:` and implements the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol. Then in `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` you can update your global state to handle a logout (i.e. broadcast a notification through `NSNotificationCenter`, make a custom AppDelegate call, etc.).

Comment: NIce - thanks man. I'm working on this app for a client , and that's what they requested. I will bring up that it is unintuitive design and see if a whole view would make more sense for logging out - Thanks Paul!